# Add Script to all files created in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

As a request from a client I was asked to make a 'Datetime' addition to Google Docs. Basically what they wanted was an easy way to insert the Date & Time into a document file. They use this file as a communication log between their counselors and their sites. I've created the script and it works great. The only problem is that it only applies to the specific file I add it to. Which is an issue because they create a new file for every month.

What I would like to do is be able to apply the script to every document that gets created in that specific folder since the only thing that gets created in that folder is the communication log files for each month.

I'm curious if there is a way to do this. An easy way since I'm not much of a programmer.

Here is the code that I have written for getting the datetime. What it does is creates a "Custom" tab in navigation of the document with a drop down to select "Datetime" which places the Datetime where ever the cursor location is.

```js
function onOpen() {
  // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom')
      .addItem('Insert Date', 'insertAtCursor')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Inserts the date at the current cursor location in boldface.
 */
function insertAtCursor() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();

  if (cursor) {
    // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
    // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm - "); // "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    var element = cursor.insertText(date);
    if (element) {
      element.setBold(false);
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
    }
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }
}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible unless you pubish it as an addon (and optionally have their domain admin auto-add it to all users).
An alternative is to have a monthly process (use triggers) that
 1) creates a spreadsheet copy, names it and organizes it on a folder

2) empties the current spreadsheet to start the month. 
This way you always keep the script in the original spreadsheet.
to prevent catching users by surprise as they work on the sheet, open a sidebar for confirmation of the monthly backup process or use an hourly trigger so you can control the time and only do it at 4am on the first day of the month for example.

Comment: Thanks Zig, I'm the domain admin and have been trying to figure out how to publish the script as an addon but I just can't find good work ups on how to go about doing that. This whole thing has been a bit outside of my wheelhouse. Unfortunately I don't think the Google supplied documentation is all that great. Do you by chance have any resources for pointing me in a good direction to figure out how to build addons?

Comment: not really other than the official docs. Maybe its best if you go route #2

Answer (score 0):

Zig's answer of an Add-on is a good one. As now a domain admin can push it to all users via the app marketplace.

The other options is to use a trigger builder.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder

These are odd creatures as the code you want to execute in the document does not reside in the document, but in another script. The script has to be ran as someone who has permissions to the file though.

```
function addMenuItem() {
  // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom')
      .addItem('Insert Date', 'insertAtCursor')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Inserts the date at the current cursor location in boldface.
 */
function insertAtCursor() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();

  if (cursor) {
    // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
    // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm - "); // "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    var element = cursor.insertText(date);
    if (element) {
      element.setBold(false);
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
    }
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }
}

 function buildTrigger(fileId){
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('addMenuItem')
   .forDocument(fileId)
   .onOpen()
   .create();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer. I'm looking into building a proper addon but not sure where the hell to even start. This is not really my area of expertise so I'm struggling a bit to figure out how to do it exactly. But thanks for the response.